# Can SVG <img> support Parameter strings?

Tags: html, svg, query-string

I have been using SVG assets recently in my code and I have not looked back. Quality and ease of editing has been a big factor for me.

My problem is that I want to have the colors dynamic insert the fill tags.

So

```
Nike.svg?color=fff 
Nike.svg?color=000
```

Rather than having to open the SVG, edit the fill tags and then make a NikeWhite.svg and a NikeBlack.svg

Apparently this (http://www.schepers.cc/w3c/svg/params/ref.html) works  but it is only for `<object>` tags and I need to have it support for `<img>` without JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think you can without js, and you can't run js from `<img>` tag, nor access its content through js btw.

Comment: You would have to have inline svg and then give them different classes to create a black and white svg.

Comment: Inlining the SVG would give you more options to format its contents via your page’s stylesheet (see https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) Apart from that, I think the most you could possibly do without any scripting is to use URL hashes (`Nike.svg#foo`), and then format elements based on whether the element inside the SVG with the id `foo` is currently targeted (`:target` pseudo class) or not, via a stylesheet that is embedded into the SVG directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.  SVG does not support parameters like that.

That document you link to is only a proposal by Doug Schepers.  It has not been accepted, nor has been implemented by any of the browsers.

Comment: Ah I thought this was a fully supported document.